# How to convert epoch to date in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I receive ohlc data from Kraken with EPOCH time in ms. Es: 1599651300

When I plot the data, I see the epoch number, but I would like to see a date (es: 10-Sep-2020 12:23).

How can I do it?

```
ohlc, last = k.get_ohlc_data("BCHEUR", 5)

# plot candlestick chart
candle = go.Candlestick(
    x = ohlc['time'],
    open = ohlc['open'],
    close = ohlc['close'],
    high = ohlc['high'],
    low = ohlc['low'],
    name = "Candlesticks")

data = [candle]

# style and display
layout = go.Layout()
fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
plot(fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this answer, I am assuming that `ohlc` is a dataframe. In that case, before plotting you can convert  `ohlc['time']` to regular readable datetime as the following:

```
ohlc['time'] = pd.to_datetime(ohlc['time'],unit='s')
```

Or

```
ohlc['time'] = ohlc['time'].map(lambda x : pd.Timestamp(x, unit='s'))
```

Input :

```
>>> ohlc
         time
0  1599651300
```

Output :

```
>>> ohlc
                 time
0 2020-09-09 11:35:00
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got strange dates:
Now all the points has the same day: Jan 19, 1970, and different hours.

I checked the data source and epoch number are corrects:
print(ohlc['time'][0]) //1599654000

Unfortunatly I don't know how to share the source data. Kraken api are private.

Comment: @FabioDev Can you share head of `ohlc` dataframe? Also, can you try `unit='s'`?

Comment: @FabioDev I have updated the answer, can you try this one?